# React useEffect on dom element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have two "buttons" (they're div elements with an onClick attached). Each one changes a product's price inside a div element.

How can I do something when that div was clicked, inside another component ?

Can I somehow put dom element to the dependencies array of an useEffect ?

for example:

```
useEffect(() => {
// Do stuff
}, [document.getElementById('div-that-shows-price')])
```

I tried the above, didn't work. I even tried it with .textContent, innerHTML, ....

I'm guessing I can't use ref because again, they're in different components. Or  can I use a ref defined in a component from another one ?

Comment: I think we need more context in order to really be helpful. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Is the div rendered by React code? Is that other component in the same component tree as the one where you want to do this?

Comment: I dont understand the question. `How can I do something when that div was clicked, inside another component ` mean after u click `div`, inside add another component, or update, or delete or what ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `useRef` hook:

https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: But can I access that ref in another component? I can't give it as props, because they're not direct child/parent

Comment: What you try to achieve is not clear. Maybe you need a reducer?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. But from what I understand, why don't you pass price as props to another component? You can put product price in a parent component state and pass it as props (with updatePrice method) in both button components. Or use global state (redux).

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, what you building is basically counter, in one div you want count aka price to be able to incremented and decremented, and in the other div you would like to see the button click result. Since you're using React, this is achieved by `useState()` and just passing result prop from parent component div which would have the button to the child component div.